# How to get time from date object without time zone in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have Date object like

```
Date {Mon Aug 17 2015 05:45:23 GMT+0530 (IST)}
```

i want only time without GMT  timezone and IST.I want only time like 05:45:23.thanks

Comment: Use [Date methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) javascript library to format and process your dates. 
The alternative option is manually accessing date hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: How its possible in moment.js.example pls

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Date Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).
You can build a string by using:

```
var formattedDate = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
```

Comment: If time is on AM then getting 1:1:5 how to get in 2 digit

Comment: You have to check that yourself since the function doesn't return with leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure JavaScript:

```
var d = new Date(),
hours = d.getHours(),
mins = d.getMinutes(),
secs = d.getSeconds(),
time = hours + ':' + mins + ':' + secs;
console.log(time);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own prototype extending the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

```
Date.prototype.extractTime = function(){
  var h = this.getHours();
  var m = this.getMinutes();
  var s = this.getSeconds();

  return h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}
```

#### Usage:

```
var d = new Date();
d.extractTime();    // outputs current time of your clock..
```

Comment: By far the best option for repeat usage.